# The dp is suitable for phone but too small for tablet in android

Tags: android, android-layout, pixel, tablet

I worked on a app that fit on the phone, but now I need to make it fit for the tablet. The problem is , for the same dp , it works well on phone, however, for the tablet , it is too small ,  I have searched for the solution like this:

http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Found that the dp on tablet is double / triple of the phone. So , if I would like to define a custom actionbar size like the following, how can I fit it to the tablet as well? 60 dp is suitable for phone 4"~5" but too small for 7"~10" tablet

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">60dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Android handle resources allows developers to specify different dimensions based on screen sizes. In your XML layouts you could have:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/subtitle_container_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

...

</FrameLayout>
```

And that value will be specified in different folders, each one specific for your needs.

Considering that your `res` directory have a similar structure like the one below:

```
res/
    values
    values-sw400dp
    values-sw720dp
```

you can create a `dimens.xml` file in each of these folders containing:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="subtitle_container_width">(VALUE IN DP)</dimen>
</resources>
```

Android will consider the correct value in runtime for you, automatically.
In this example, you can have a specific dimension for devices with the smallest width of 720dp and 400dp. If a device does not have at least 400dp, the default value in the `values` folder will be used.

You can create more folders to suit your needs, with different sizes or modifiers (smallest dimension of X, minimum height of Y and so on).

You can find more info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html